# Style for PrefenceScreen

Tags: android

I'd like to be able to customize the view of a `PreferenceScreen`, and so I'm interested in knowing how to set a style for it.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't recommend it but you can start extending all the preference's classes (`DialogPreference`, `CheckboxPreference`, etc) and create your own widgets with the style you want.

Comment: I'm interested only in the PreferenceScreen . I'd like to increase the font size for the text that the PreferenceScreen displays it (the one speficied in the android:title tag)

Comment: @klaus-vlad did you try extending it and changing that through the code?

Comment: Could you point me exactly where the modifications should be made ?

Comment: @klaus-vlad: Never did it myself, but that's what I would try. Sorry.

Comment: PreferenceScreen class is final and cannot be extended

Comment: @klaus-vlad: oh, that's bad. It also doesn't have any method for what you are trying to do :(

Comment: What I've tried is to use the android:layout attribute to set a different layout. The layout I've tried to set is actually the android original layout with the not public resources  removed and the textAppereance atribute value modified. The problem is that with this approach the widget and the summery of the preference screen are lost.

Answer (score 0):

Try this for increasing font size in onResume():

```
Window window = getActivity().getWindow();
window.getContext().setTheme(R.style.PreferencesTheme);
```

and create a style PreferencesTheme in layout/styles.xml file:

```
<style name="PreferencesTheme">
<item name="android:textColor">#000000</item>

    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">40sp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingLeft">0sp</item>
    <item name="android:colorBackground">#0000ff</item>
</style>
```